# My VPS windows server 2008 R2 is blocking IP

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2, vps, windows-firewall

A client can not connect to the VPS because the server blocks it.

He has to change several times his IP to conect. This is a serious problem. I have a rule in the firewall where I allow his conection always to the server but it is not working. why?

Comment: You need to do a LOT more troubleshooting for this question to be answerable. [See this Meta topic for some tips](http://meta.serverfault.com/questions/3608/how-can-i-ask-better-questions-on-server-fault)

Answer (score 1):

It's practically guaranteed that your "client" has a dynamic IP assigned by DHCP, meaning that he gets a new external IP every so often.

You won't be able to filter by IP alone, as you've already seen. Try going up one netblock and see if that's a big enough net to allow his ISP's netblock. For example, if you're allowing 198.51.100.34, try allowing everything in 198.51.100.X. If not, work on a better authentication mechanism using SSL certificates or similar.

Comment: The "client" has fixed IP, is because he has to change the IP to conect is really a problem.